# Cannot move a register to a register of a different size

Tags: assembly, x86, cpu-registers, mov

When I write this:

```
mov cx,dh
mov dx,dl
```

It makes an error:

```
invalid combination of opcode and operands
```

I'm a beginner at assembly language so I need help!

Comment: `mov` only works if both operands are the same size. On a 386 or higher system you can use `movsx` or `movzx` if the destination operand is larger than the source operand. The reverse operation is never valid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ```
> mov cx,dh
> ```

The error message you get for `mov cx, dh` means that the size of the CX destination register (16 bits) is different from the size of the DH source register (8 bits). For most instructions, operands must be the same size.

There are several ways to do `mov cx, dh`.

```
   unsigned              signed
   --------              ------

1) movzx cx, dh       1) movsx cx, dh       ; 80386+

                      2) mov   ch, dh       ; 80186+
                         sar   cx, 8

2) mov   cl, dh       3) mov   al, dh       ; 8086+
   mov   ch, 0           cbw
                         mov   cx, ax

3) xor   cx, cx       4) mov   ch, dh
   mov   cl, dh          mov   cl, 8
                         sar   cx, cl

4) mov   al, 1        5) mov   al, 1
   mul   dh              imul  dh
   mov   cx, ax          mov   cx, ax
```

There are several ways to do `mov dx, dl`.

```
   unsigned              signed
   --------              ------

1) movzx dx, dl       1) movsx dx, dl       ; 80386+

                      2) mov   dh, dl       ; 80186+
                         sar   dx, 8

2) mov   dh, 0        3) xchg  ax, dx       ; 8086+
                         cbw
                         xchg  dx, ax

3) mov   al, 1        4) mov   dh, dl
   mul   dl              mov   cl, 8
   mov   dx, ax          sar   dx, cl

                      5) mov   al, 1
                         imul  dl
                         mov   dx, ax
```

There are several ways to do `mov cx, dh` `mov dx, dl`.

```
   unsigned              signed
   --------              ------

1) movzx cx, dh       1) movsx cx, dh       ; 80386+
   xor   dh, dh          movsx dx, dl

2) xor   cx, cx       2) mov   ch, dh       ; 8086+
   xchg  dh, cl          mov   dh, dl
                         mov   cl, 8
                         sar   dx, cl
                         sar   cx, cl
```

Choose wise and stick with the simple ones!

Comment: `sar` with count as an immediate 8 is a 186+ instruction.

Comment: To sign-extend DL into DX before 386, you might `xchg ax,dx` / `cbw` / `xchg ax,dx`.  That avoids clobbering AX.  I think use-cases like that are why 8086 included a 1-byte short-form for exchange-with-accumulator for the full register.